# Android: Testing room migration

Tags: android, database, android-room, android-testing

I have a migration where I am adding a new column
The migration is defined as

```
val MIGRATION_20_21: Migration = object : Migration(20, 21) {
    override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
        database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE tests ADD COLUMN deleted INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0")

    }
}
```

The field is dined as

```
@ColumnInfo(name = "deleted") var deleted: Boolean = false,
```

And I have a test case for this migration which looks like

```
@Test
@Throws(IOException::class)
fun migrate20to21() {
    var db = helper.createDatabase(TEST_DB, 20).apply {
        
        addTestsToDatabase(this, true)
       
        close()
    }

    db = helper.runMigrationsAndValidate(TEST_DB, 21, true,
            MIGRATION_20_21)

    var cursor = db.query("SELECT * FROM tests WHERE id = ?", arrayOf("id0"))
    MatcherAssert.assertThat(cursor, Is(notNullValue()))
    MatcherAssert.assertThat(cursor.moveToFirst(), `is`(true))
    MatcherAssert.assertThat(cursor.getColumnIndex("deleted"), `is`(38))
    MatcherAssert.assertThat(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("deleted")), `is`(0))
```

I am getting the error Migration didn't properly handle: tests
I see a difference in expected and found table info

```
Expected: deleted=Column{name='deleted', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, local_created_at=Column{name='local_created_at', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}

Found: deleted=Column{name='deleted', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='0'}
```

Why there is a difference in default value and how can it be null when I have defined it as not null.

Answer (score 1):

> Why there is a difference in default value and how can it be null when I have defined it as not null

The reason is that **"Expected"** is derived from the Entity (at compile time) and then compared to the schema of the actual database that is being/has been opened (what has been **"Found"**), so you need to change the Entity to also have a default value of 0, using the `@ColumnInfo(defaultValue = "0")`.

Without then the default value will be null i.e. no default value specified.

- The `@ColumnInfo`'s `defaultValue` was introduced in [Room 2.2.0](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room#version_220_3), until that version the DEFAULT clause was (I believe) ignored and and expected/found conflict wouldn't arise.

So the Entity should contain

```
@ColumnInfo(defaultValue = "0")
val deleted: Int = 0
```

- Or instead of `Int = 0`, `Boolean = false`

**Amendment** re update showing:-

```
@ColumnInfo(name = "deleted") var deleted: Boolean = false,
```

then you need to use :-

```
@ColumnInfo(name = "deleted", defaultValue = "0") var deleted: Boolean = false,
```

Re the comment

> thank you. when I say var deleted: Boolean = false, is it not the same as saying defaultValue?

Correct it isn't the same.

Setting a value for var/val sets the value of the field when the value isn't provided when instantiating the object and effectively assigns the object a default value.

**Whilst** `defaultValue = "0"` says that the column definition includes the `DEFAULT 0` in the table's column definition.

e.g.

```
 `deleted` INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
```

Without you get

```
 `deleted` INTEGER NOT NULL
```

This is what Room EXPECTED (as it is without `defaultValue =`) in your case according to the Entity your ALTER column definition that was FOUND differs from the expected (no DEFAULT so Room's interpretation is defaultValue = null).

In your case the defaultValue = "0" is important as 0 (false) will be used as the value for the column for rows that existed before the ALTER, whilst null might result in run time issues.

using `var deleted: Boolean = false`, is also potentially important as it provides the default value if the value is omitted when instantiating the object.

- *Perhaps the best/easiest way to get things as Room expects is to make your Entity changes, then compile (e.g. Ctrl + F9) and to then inspect the **generated java** (easily visible from Android View in Android Studio) to then find the class that is named as per the @Database class suffixed with **_Impl** and then find the **createAllTables** method which includes the EXPECTED table definitions.*
- e.g.
- [image]

**Another Amendment**

Regarding the comment

> Does the migration uses the json files created by room?

No, UNLESS [AutoMigration](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/AutoMigration) is used. AutoMigration builds the code for the migration (I believe) at compile time and hence why it needs schemas and requires exportSchema = true and the underlying gradle schema location directive.

Migrations actually take place at run time and do not need (nor even have access to the saved schemas as I believe that they are not included in the APK).

> My current version is 24 but this field was added at version 21. SO even though I add default = 0, it only recreates 24.json. This test case for 20 to 21 fails as 21.json do not have default value.

I suspect that this could be due to different versions of Room. Prior to [2.2.0](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room#version_220_3) `defaultValue` was not an option and thus it was ignored when comparing expected and found. Noting that this comparison is undertaken after migration(s) have been performed (I believe ALL migrations).

Comment: I have updated my question. I have defined it as @ColumnInfo(name = "deleted") var deleted: Boolean = false,

Comment: thank you. when I say var deleted: Boolean = false, is it not the same as saying defaultValue?

Comment: @png edited the answer to explain that they are different

Comment: @png I've also added a Q & A  that hopefully explains the difference in more detail at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68356329/how-do-i-utilise-the-equivalent-of-sqlites-default-a-value-in-android-room/68356330#68356330

Comment: Does the migration uses the json files created by room? My current version is 24 but this field was added at version 21. SO even though I add default = 0, it only recreates 24.json. This test case for 20 to 21 fails as 21.json do not have default value. I see my test case failing. I want to confirm thats the reason

Comment: Sorry, I am running in to new doubts. If verification is based on the @enitiy, definition, old migration test cases can get broken as u keep changing the Entity. Is that right. Like u removed a column?

Comment: @png Migration, UNLESS it's AutoMigration, doesn't use the saved schema (if one is saved i.e. you can still migrate with `exportSchema = false`). Old migrations shouldn't get broken, as the migrations are based upon the version stored in the database and the version number coded and passed to the databasebuilder.  @ColumnInfo's `defaultValue=` is a more recent change (introduced in 2.2.0) so it may be that the issue has only come to head when a newer version of Room was introduced.